# Store multiple number of repeated data using get set method

Tags: java

I have a class like this..

```
public static class FlightInfoDetails {
    static String FlightNumber;
    static String DepartureDate;
    static String DepartureTime;

    public static void setFlightNumber(String pstrData) {
        FlightNumber= pstrData;
    }

    public static void setDepartureDate(String pstrData) {
        DepartureDate = pstrData;
    }

    public static void setDepartureTime(String pstrData) {
        DepartureTime = pstrData;
    }

    public static String getFlightNumber()
    {
        return FlightNumber;
    }

    public static String getDepartureDate()
    {
        return DepartureDate;
    }
}
```

And so on. Everything was fine up to this, but now I need to deal with multiple number of
`FlightInfoDetails`. When I tried to call that set method the previous  data gets lost. Can anybody help?

Comment: you need more than one instance of this class. Therefore call `new` several times, (e.g in an array or list).

Comment: Create a new instance of your class before adding the element in the `List`.

Comment: Yah, even my colleague also suggested me to use List... But the problem is I don't know how to create list for class. If you don't mine pls send some code snippet or any ref links.... please do some needful.

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you want to be able to create many instances of the FlightInfoDetails class, you should get rid of the `static` modifiers you have.

```
public class FlightInfoDetails {
String FlightNumber;
String DepartureDate;
String DepartureTime;
public void setFlightNumber(String pstrData) {
    FlightNumber= pstrData;
}
public void setDepartureDate(String pstrData) {
    DepartureDate = pstrData;
}

public void setDepartureTime(String pstrData) {
    DepartureTime = pstrData;
}
public String getFlightNumber()
{
    return FlightNumber;
}
public String getDepartureDate()
{
    return DepartureDate;
}
}
```

Now you shouldn't have any issues creating more than one FlightInfoDetails object, or setting the data for each object. In a main method, you can create an ArrayList of these objects.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
        ArrayList<FlightInfoDetails> flightList = new ArrayList<FlightInfoDetails>():
        FlightInfoDetails info = new FlightInfoDetails();
        flightList.add(info);
        FlightInfoDetails info2 = new FlightInfoDetails();
        flightList.add(info2);

        info.setDepartureDate("May 20, 2013");
        info2.setDepartureDate("June 10, 2013");
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I can store the data but now I am facing problem while retrieving it FlightDetail=FlightInfoDetails.getFlightDetailList().get(0); Please help me how to retrieve it.

Comment: `FlightInfoDetails info = FlightInfoDetails.getFlightDetailsList.get(0);`

Answer (score 2):

- Add a new instance of your `FlightInfoDetails` class.

`FlightInfoDetails details = new FlightInfoDetails();`

- Call setter methods as necessary on this instance.

`details.setDepartureDate("12/12/2013");`

- Store this instance in a `List`:

`List<FlightInfoDetails> detailsList = new ArrayList<FlightInfoDetails>();`

`detailsList.add(details);`

Note: Ensure you remove all `static` modifiers from your `FlightInfoDetails` class so that you can create instances of this class.

Comment: Thank you.. I can store the data but now I am facing problem while retrieving it  FlightDetail=FlightInfoDetails.getFlightDetailList().get(0); Please help me how to retrieve it.